# A question on Simulink

Tags: matlab

I've done a simulation with Simulink.

Now I want to do the next thing:

extract the specific graph that I want and to mark some point on the graph that it will be displayed. like in the next pic:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the block named "to workspace" and record the interesting input/output signals.

Then use the regular plot functionality in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I managed to do it by myself, I just found the Data Cursor is what I needed. :-D

Comment: BTWת How can I copy a plot with the data cursor and its axes labels included. I am trying to do this, and I don't see how?

Comment: Never mind, fix that too.